# HTTP Header and body has unexpected padding between them

Tags: http

After the end of the header data at \r\n\r\n, I expect the beginning of the body data. This does happen for some requests, however, some of them after the \r\n\r\n I get a copy of the first 4 bytes of the body data + a random amount of zeros then the real start of the body data.

Is there an explanation for why this happens or how I can prevent it?

The request I sent is HTTP 1.0 GET, and I believe the server is Apache, I don't know, it's hosted with new technologies so I would assume this is not a problem on that end.

[image]

Comment: Add here your work, explain where you are stuck. Currently, you have added just a problem.

Comment: Well I just don't know why it does this. I have tried fixes for it, such as going past the first 4 bytes then searching for the first non-zero but this bug does not happen on all files so that would not work for other files. I was mainly wondering if anybody knows why it does this. Maybe it's some weird alignment or something I do not know about HTTP protocol.